# Short way to run gradle task on subproject

Tags: gradle, gradlew

So, using gradle 5.6.1, I have a project with several nested modules/projects:

```
root
├── A
└── B
    └── C
        └── D
```

Now, if I was using maven, I could do

```
mvn clean install -pl :D
```

but in gradle it seems I need to type:

```
./gradle :B:C:D:assemble
```

which means I need to know and type the full path to the module/subproject.

Is there any shorter way, some way to pass only `:D` ?

ps: I'm also using gw (https://github.com/srs/gw) if relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this via a [task rule](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_rules). Eg:

```
tasks.addRule("Pattern: -Pproject=<PROJECT> <TASK>") { String taskName ->
   def projectProp = findProperty('project')
   if (projectProp) {
      def matchingTasks = getTasksByName(taskName, true).findAll { it.project.name == projectProp }
      if (matchingTasks) { 
         task(taskName) {
            dependsOn matchingTasks
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then on command line

```
gradle -Pproject=D assemble
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I may not be able to introduce that on the codebase, but will try :)

Comment: If you just wanted it for yourself, for all builds, you could do it via an [init script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html). Eg in `USER_HOME/.gradle/init.gradle`

Comment: how can I access the tasks object from an init script @lance-java ? I get an error while running the init script: > Could not get unknown property 'tasks' for build of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.

Comment: Unlike a `build.gradle` (which executes against a [Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) instance), an init script executes against a [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/invocation/Gradle.html) instance. So you could do something like `rootProject { tasks.addRule(...) }`

Answer (score 0):

it seems that currently there's no proper way to achieve this